# The table input step does not execute when variable substitution is done for the query in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Below is the query.

> select * from tablex where c_trans_date>= (select
>   CONVERT(DATETIME,concat(1,'-',(substring('${SHORT_FILENAME}',charindex('.','${SHORT_FILENAME}',1)-5,3)),'-',substring('${SHORT_FILENAME}',charindex('.','${SHORT_FILENAME}',1)-2,2)),121))
>   and c_trans_date<=(select CONVERT(DATETIME,dateadd(day,-1,(select
>   dateadd(month,1,(select
>   concat(1,'-',(substring('${SHORT_FILENAME}',charindex('.','${SHORT_FILENAME}',1)-5,3)),
>   '-',substring('${SHORT_FILENAME}',charindex('.','${SHORT_FILENAME}',1)-2,2)))))),121))

The error says

```
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Spoon - Transformation opened.
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Spoon - Launching transformation [STATEX_DATA_PULL]...
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Spoon - Started the transformation execution.
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - STATEX_DATA_PULL - Dispatching started for transformation [STATEX_DATA_PULL]
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 - Couldn't get row from result set
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 - 
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2374)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2344)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2322)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.doQuery(TableInput.java:247)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.processRow(TableInput.java:138)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 - Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:4853)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1781)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:1034)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2362)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 -   ... 6 more
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Input table.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - STATEX_DATA_PULL - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - STATEX_DATA_PULL - Transformation is killing the other steps!
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - STATEX_DATA_PULL - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - Spoon - The transformation has finished!!
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - STATEX_DATA_PULL - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2017/08/18 10:25:54 - STATEX_DATA_PULL - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
```

BTW, It works fine when query is executed in SQLServer.

Answer (score 1):

*Ahhrggg... Oh No ... Please Nooooo ... DateTimeFormat runs in MS-server but not in PDI ... Not that one ... Not again...*

First check the `Enable Lazy Conversion` checkbox on the `Input Table` step is NOT on.

If the problem persist, you can try to edit the connection. On the left panel, select `Advanced` and check/uncheck the `Support timestamp data type`.

If the problem persist, then you have to find out where. Read the table with a SELECT * and try to convert the Dates with an `Select Value`/`Metadata` step and play with the format.

If you still cannot find the bug, try to solve the problem in a more PDI style rather that in one sql. As far as I understand, the data format depends on the `${SHORT_FILENAME}`, so you can use that variable to `Switch/Case` to the appropriate `Select Value`/`Metadata`/`Date Format`, and migrate your sub select in the corresponding `Lookups` and `Filter Rows`. [And please, make me the favor of running a test BEFORE complaining about bad performance].

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more support?